# SQL - Counting data types and printing highest occurrence first

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am required to produce a list of the different types of pets with a count of how many there are of each ignoring when there is only one type of pet. This should also be listed in descending order. The columns available in my pet table are as follows pet_id, Name, Type, Breed, Gender, Born, owner_id and Notes. But only the Type will be utilised as far as I know.

Below is what I have attempted thus far but it clearly needs improvement and please note this will be executed within Microsoft Access.

```
SELECT COUNT(Type)
FROM pet
ORDER BY Type DESC;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `GROUP BY` the type:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Type)
FROM pet
GROUP BY Type
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(Type) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but it only displays the count. I would like to have the type of pet next to it. For example Dog | 4, Cat | 2, Fish | 2. Currently I just get 4, 2, 2.

Comment: This should display the Type and the Count

Comment: I thought it would aswell but it only shows numbers. Could be something to do with mircrosoft access.

Comment: @DAN212 Perhaps field `Type` is of numeric type and is just a `FK` to a lookup table that contains the description of each type. If this is the case, then you have to join to this table.

Comment: Does this version work any better? `SELECT [Type], COUNT([Type]) FROM pet GROUP BY [Type] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT([Type]) DESC;`

Comment: Thanks HansUp. Displays the name aswell as the count now. Thanks aswell Giorgos.

Comment: Interesting.  `Type` is a [troublesome choice](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T) for a field name.  Maybe that was confusing Access.  The square brackets signal the db engine that `[Type]` is a field name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Type) as cnt
FROM pet
group by Type
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```